# Manter state da Store do Redux em cache

Tags: react, redux

Olá, eu sou novo em toda a questão de react e redux então queria uma ajudinha. Fiz um código simples:

#### home.js

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import { authLoginSucesso, authLoginErro, authLogout } from '../../actions/auth.action';

class Home extends Component {

    render() {
        const { isAuth, authLoginSucesso, authLoginErro, authLogout } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="container">
               { 
                  isAuth ? <div>Está autenticado</div>
                  : <div>Não está autenticado</div>
              }
              <button onClick={ () => authLoginSucesso() }>
                 Logar
              </button>

              <button onClick={ () => authLoginErro() }>
                 Erro logar
              </button>

              <button onClick={ () => authLogout() }>
                 LogOut
              </button>
           </div>
          );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
    isAuth: store.auth.isAuth
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators({ authLoginSucesso, authLoginErro, authLogout }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

#### auth.action.js

```js
export const authLoginSucesso = () => async dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
        type: 'AUTH_LOGIN_SUCESSO'
    })
}

export const authLoginErro = () => async dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
        type: 'AUTH_LOGIN_ERRO'
    })
}

export const authLogout = () => async dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
        type: 'AUTH_LOGOUT'
    })
}
```

#### auth.reducer.js

```js
const initialState = {
    isAuth: false
};

export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'AUTH_LOGIN_SUCESSO':
            return { isAuth: true };

        case 'AUTH_LOGIN_ERRO':
            return { isAuth: false };
            
        case 'AUTH_LOGOUT':
            return { isAuth: false };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

#### store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { rootReducers } from './rootReducers';

const initialValue = {}

export const Store = createStore(rootReducers, initialValue, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

#### rootReducers.js

```js
import { authReducer } from '../reducers/auth.reducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export const rootReducers = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer
});
```

Isso foi só para testar como o redux se comportaria em uma tela de login, quando o cara desse logout, login com sucesso e falha no Login.

Porem notei que o estado padrão de `isAuth` é `false` então o componente `home.js` renderiza com o testo "Não está autenticado", então clico no botão "Logar", ele muda o state para true, atualiza a store, a mensagem muda para "Está autenticado" normalmente, porém quando dou F5 na página, ele começa o componente como "Não está autenticado", o state voltou para o valor padrão, não deveria manter os dados em cache?

Como que faço para armazenar esses dados no cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar esse processo o ideal é utilizar esse cara que ira lhe auxiliar em relação de armazenar os dados localmente no frontend

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist